# Left Join Returns duplicate Values

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Hello everyone i'm trying to implement query where i need to take id from one table and use it in another table**[image: strong text]**

Battery is my main class, which contains capacity_id

[image]

Capacity entity contains int field 'name'

I want to implement a query where i recieve all batteries which capacity_names for example are <35 and >20

When i used left join, this operation returned me multiple duplicated rows, i need only unique one.

Here is my custom query:

```
select * from battery LEFT JOIN capacity on capacity.name > 25 and capacity.name < 35
```

Comment: `name` is an odd Name for an integer column

Answer (score 2):

You need to join each battery record on to its ***actual*** capacity record, using the `ON` clause.

Then you can ***also*** filter to only include instances where the name is in the desired range.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  battery
INNER JOIN
  capacity
    ON capacity.id = battery.capacity_id
WHERE
      capacity.name > 25
  AND capacity.name < 35
```

What you were doing was joining each and every battery *(no filtering of which batteries you get)* on to all capacities in the desired range *(causing the duplication)*, whether or not that battery actually had that capacity.